# Condition for a Markov process.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

In one of my [questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/401859/what-are-the-assumptions-underlying-the-master-equation) on PSE there is a debate in the comments about whether:
 $$P(n,t+\Delta t)=\sum_m^M P(m,t)P(n,t+\Delta t\mid m,t)\tag{$\star$}$$
holds for general stochastic processes or just for a Markovian processes. Given the vote distribution on the comments several people appear to think that it does only hold for a Markovian. Please can someone explain to me if this or isn't the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure on your notation, but I'm pretty sure it means
$$ P(n,t) = \mathbb{P}(X_t = n)
\quad\text{and}\quad
P(n,t+\Delta t \mid m,t) = \mathbb{P}(X_{t+\Delta t} = n \mid X_t = m)?$$
It's quite confusing to use $n$ and $m$ for the location, since it's often used for a discrete time process! As such, I'm going to use $i$ and $j$, just to be completely clear. Also, it isn't at all clear what your sum is over; I assume over the whole space?

**Given this, it holds for any process.** Indeed, let's derive the result, using only basic probabilistic results (law of total probability/expectation/Bayes' theorem, whatever you want to call it!):
$$ \mathbb{P}(X_{t+s} = i) = \sum_j \mathbb{P}(X_{t+s} = i \mid X_t = j) \mathbb{P}(X_t = j). \tag{$\star$} $$
I've literally done almost nothing here. I've just used that
$$ \mathbb{P}(A) = \sum_j \mathbb{P}(A \mid B_j) \mathbb{P}(B_j) $$
where $\{B_j\}_j$ partitions the space (ie 'gives all the options'). Assuming my interpretation of your notation, my $(\star)$ is exactly the same as yours.

I don't know what the other terms in your linked question mean, so I can't help with that unfortunately. The interesting part about a Markovian process is that they *usually* are time-homogeneous, in the sense that
$$ \mathbb{P}(X_{t+s} = i \mid X_t = j) = \mathbb{P}(X_s = i \mid X_0 = j). $$
(There is theory on time-inhomogeneous Markov chains, but this these are studied much less, for better or worse.) Note that this condition *does not* require the chain to be Markovian. However, how would one usually prove this property? -- by using the Markov property.

Hence, for small $s = \Delta t$, you can 'not worry about the past'. Without really understanding what the notation means, I think that in your linked question the second bullet point implicitly uses this, and hence **is only valid for a Markovian process**.

Comment: The property in your last equation describes time-homogeneity, and may or may not hold for a Markov process.

Comment: Ah yes, of course! However, I feel the standard definition of a Markov chain is that of a time homogeneous chain, but you're right that in a question like this I should have been explicit!

Comment: @SamT Thanks for this answer. FYI your interpretation of the notation is correct - sorry I should have being more explicit in the question.